# What is the difference between "select <text>" and "print <text>" in T-SQL?

Tags: t-sql, select, sap-ase

In T-SQL, I can send text to output using either 
     `select 'mytext'`
or
     `print 'mytext'`

I usually get the same result.  However, occasionally `select` silently fails to output any text, whereas `print` always works.

What is the difference between the two?  Why might `select` sometimes fail?   (FYI my system is Sybase ASE version 15.)

Comment: PRINT is not a standard SQL command - it's probably Sybase specific. SELECT, on the other hand, is part of the ANSI standard and supported by all RDBMS.

Comment: Don't know about sybase, but in SQL SERVER there's a big difference since PRINT can only write a string message, it can't actually return tabular data. Since Sybase uses TSQL, I think it's the same there.

Answer (score 4):

In `sql-server 2012`

i executed these

```
SELECT getdate() -- returned 2013-11-27 17:37:51.080

PRINT getdate() --returned Nov 27 2013  5:37PM
```

so you summarize as

`PRINT` always returns a char or varchar,so when you make `PRINT GETDATE()` an implicit conversion is made.

`SELECT` returns the datatype supplied.

Answer (score 2):

If you use SQL Server Management Studio's query option: "Results to File"

- **SELECT** will go to the file
- **PRINT**  will go to the "Messages" pane at the bottom of the Query Editor.

As according to the [MSSQL 2012 documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176047(v=sql.110).aspx)

```
PRINT Returns a user-defined message to the client.
```